# How to parse request parameters in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I want to have a url such as `http://mydomain.com/token/abc12345` where abc12345 is a variable parameter.

When angular sees this URL, I want it to extract the token, do a database lookup, put some stuff in the scope and then send the user to a particular page that displays some of this data.

If the user goes to `http://mydomain.com/` I want it to show some sort of error message. I.e. the only valid entry point into the application is via the token URL.

How can I set this up in Angular? What would my $routeProvider definitions look like?

Comment: Your route template url should be 'myurl/:token' format. If the token is not provided it routes to otherwise route.

Answer (score 0):

try this way to your controller

```
if($routeParams.tokenId== undefined)
{
 alert("wrong url")
 return false;
}
//next code
```

**Explanation for the code**

> This code for get query string value. SO if your  url does not have any query string, then it's show the alert (or you can redirect to error screen). Otherwise it's call next code.

Answer (score 0):

In your route definition file do something like this;

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'error.html',
            controller: 'ErrorCtrl'
        })
        .when('/token/:tokenid', {
            templateUrl: 'yourview.html',
            controller: 'TokenCtrl'
        })
});
```

And in `ErrorCtrl`

```
app.controller('ErrorCtrl', function () {
  alert('wrong page');
});
```

And in `TokenCtrl`

```
app.controller('TokenCtrl', function ($routeParams) {
  var token = routeParams.tokenid;
   //Do your rest of the stuff
});
```